# BMP180 sensor not updating temperature when I put my finger on it

Tags: python, flask, arduino

So I wanted to start a project that would allow me to check the temperature inside my room from the internet. I used an Arduino Nano, Raspberry pi 3 B+, and a BMP180 sensor. I was able to check the temperature using the local IP address, but the temperature doesn't seem to be updating properly. I put my finger on the sensor and refresh the page, but the temperature stays the same.

This is python script A:

```py
import serial
arduino = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 115200)

def temp():
    while (arduino.inWaiting()==0):
        pass
    arduinoString = arduino.readline()
    decodedData = arduinoString.decode()
    return decodedData
```

This is python script B:

```py
from A import temp

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def func():
    data = temp()
    return (data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80, debug=True)
```

This is the script running on Arduino:

```
include "Wire.h"
include "Adafruit_BMP085.h"
Adafruit_BMP085 mySensor;

float tempC;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  mySensor.begin();
}

void loop() {
  tempC = mySensor.readTemperature();
  Serial.println(tempC);
  delay(250);
}
```

I want to update the temperature whenever I refresh the page, but it stays the same. I put my finger on the sensor and refresh the page. The sensor does, however, update when I put my finger on it according to the Serial Monitor, but not on the webpage when I refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for test I created very simple program and upload it to Arduino:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
    for (int i=1; i<11; i++) {
        Serial.print("message :");
        Serial.println(i);
        delay(250);
    }
}
```

I would highly recommended to create a TemperatureSensor python object:

TemperatureSensor will have attribute data with hold current value of readed temperature.

TemperatureSensor will handle all stuff related to read and handle data = constant reading data from serial preventing overflow/overstack data on bus.

```
# file sensor.py
import serial
import time
import threading

class TemperatureSensor:
    def __init__(self, port, baud_rate):
        self.port = port
        self.baud_rate = baud_rate
        self.data = ''
        self.init_connection()
        threading.Thread(target=self.read_data).start()

    def init_connection(self):
        try:
           self.arduino = serial.Serial(self.port, self.baud_rate)
        except Exception as e:
            # HANDLE THIS ERROR
            print('cannot create connection, exception:', e)

    def read_data(self):
        while True:
            while (self.arduino.inWaiting() == 0):
                pass
            readed_data = self.arduino.readline()
            self.data = readed_data.decode()
            time.sleep(0.25)
```

After that You can just:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import datetime
from .sensor import TemperatureSensor

temperature_sensor = TemperatureSensor(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
                                       baud_rate=115200)

@app.route("/")
def func():
    return (temperature_sensor.data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80, debug=True
```

Remember to add init.py due to importing.

I crated similar project, You can check class in my repo:
https://github.com/t1waz/alternative_station/blob/master/alternative_station/scanner.py

Cheers,
Fenrir